# Note 3 keyboard saves URLs I type into incognito tab

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Just purchased a Note 3 recently.  I'm using the stock keyboard.  When I go into an incognito tab within Chrome and type in a URL, then later on in the day return to Chrome (regular tab). When I tap in the URL field the keyboard pops up with the last three URLs I typed in.  One of which being the one I used in incognito. Any idea of how to stop this from happening?

(If the answer is technical I'm an Apple guy so keep it plain English. Thanks.)

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything to be done about that. The keyboard has no idea you're in an Incognito tab in Chrome, which really only protects you from having cookies or history saved _within Chrome_. I'm sure Samsung has made their own version of the keyboard; the [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) may or may not recognize that it's being used in Chrome, but it couldn't hurt to try.